# Javascript , loading progress bar before site loads

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a progress bar for a GUI site that I am making and I need a bit of code in javascript to detect if the site is loading and how many elements/images have loaded and has the site fully loaded.
I have the progress bar made with css and I dont know how I can turn on/of elements in js.

How can I accomplish this in js or by using Jquery ?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: You'd be better off spending your time optimizing your page load so that you don't need to entertain users with a "please wait while this slow site loads" animation.

Answer (score 2):

Some solutions to achieve what you want are:

- Code a really little page with nothing but your favourite js framework (jQuery maybe?) and a little code that requests the rest of the elements of the page dinamically with AJAX counting which ones are finished or not with the load events.
- For images you can also link "load" event and do a progress bar counting the total images grated/images loaded.
- Other combiantions of the other two.

Comment: Congrats for making this answerable, I didn't think it was.

Comment: Anyway it will require quite a work but it's doable. I've seen at least one javascript framework that works this way

Comment: To add a progress bar to an existing project what I do is to add a visible overlay div with position absolute and width and height equal to 100%, with an animated progress image inside, that I hide once the dom ready event is fired. Works like a charm and doesn't requires nothing special but just 1 line of code to hide it.